# Can cloud instances of Jupyter Lab support pop out interactive windows

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I'm new to Jupyter notebooks/Lab and I've successfully got interaction with pop-out windows and buttons etc with ipywidgets on local instances of Jupyter Lab but not in the cloud when using notebooks.ai  - the code runs without error but doesn't create the appropriate windows/button.

Is there anyway to get this working or is this an inherent restriction of using Jupyter Lab in the cloud?

I'm wondering whether there are firewall settings that need configuring to get this to work?

Comment: Do you have a minimal example? This is difficult to answer without knowing what exactly you mean by "I've successfully got interaction with pop-out windows and buttons etc with ipywidgets on local instances of Jupyter Lab." There are a variety of explanations that might be consistent with that description.

Comment: I understand that he has a code that opens pop-ups using ipywidgets that works locally but not on notebooks.ai. Although I also think that it will be useful to have an example code, it is very possible that interactive widgets are disabled in the platform (so far, I haven't seen any example using them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The X11 forwarding is disabled on the docker machines provided by `notebooks.ai`. Hence, any pop-up interaction is not being forwarded to your machine. However, you can see any inline plot/button in the Jupyter notebook.

If you are interested in this feature there is a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/notebooks-ai/notebooks-help) to request features (I have never tried it) but might be interesting for you to receive a more in-depth explanation, workaround, or solution.

**PROVE:**

In the launcher tab you can either run a notebook, a python interpreter or a terminal on the remote docker machine. If you select the terminal and type `echo $DISPLAY`, you will see that the result is an empty line (if a valid display was attached you will see something like: `DISPLAY=localhost:11.0`).

[image: notebooks ai terminal]

For further information about using BASH to check if X11 forwarding is enabled from SSH check this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253227/using-bash-to-determine-if-x11-forwarding-is-enabled-from-ssh).

Comment: Many tahnks for the detailed and helpful responses. In the end for this project I switched to javascript from within a Qualtrics questionnaire however I'll look back at this as it has great potential due to it's scalability and hopefully use it on a project soon.

Comment: @jacanterbury Consider accepting the answer if it was useful